# Android Displaying ProgressDialog inside OnResume()

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

```
     protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
                    ProgressDialog  progressDialog1 = ProgressDialog.Show(Parent, "", "Please wait...",false);
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {

            RunOnUiThread(() =>
                          {

                try
                {
                    string st="";
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {

                }
                progressDialog1.Dismiss();
            });
        })).Start();


    }
```

progress dialog is not visible when i place a break point inside the try catch block . but the same code working fine inside button click event . do any one faced the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating non - ui thread to ui thread.

you can use handler.

read following

[Handling UI code from a Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216934/handling-ui-code-from-a-thread)

Answer (score 0):

thanks.

i got the solution :- i created handler for this .

```
static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

  protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "", "Please wait...");
        loaddata();


    }
   protected void loaddata(){
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {

                string st=""; // place a break point or make the thread wait
                dialogHandler.SendEmptyMessage(0);

        })).Start();

    }
```

private Handler dialogHandler = new dialogHandlerHelper();

```
    private class dialogHandlerHelper : Handler
    {
        public dialogHandlerHelper()
        {
        }


        public override void HandleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            base.HandleMessage(msg);
            progressDialog.Dismiss();
        }
    }
```